# MySQL procedure not producing output

Tags: mysql

I am a SQL newbie. Trying to write a simple SQL procedure where I can pass Order ID (as INT) and get out put of its corresponding order status. 
Here are details:

**Table Structure:**

TransactionID    int(11) NO
   BUYEREMAIL   text    NO
   BUYERNAME    varchar(255)    NO
BUYERPHONENUMBER    text    NO
PURCHASEDATE    date    NO
PAYMENTSDATE    date    YES
METHODOFPAYMENT varchar(50) YES
SHIPPINGPRICE   int(10) YES
SHIPPINGTAX int(10) YES
SHIPSERVICELEVEL    varchar(100)    YES
SHIPADDRESS1    varchar(255)    NO
SHIPADDRESS2    varchar(255)    YES
SHIPCITY    text    NO
SHIPSTATE   text    YES
SHIPPOSTALCODE  text    NO
SHIPCOUNTRY text    NO
SHIPPHONENUMBER text    YES
OrderProcessed  bit(1)  YES
OrderStatus text    NO

**PROCEDURE**

```
 DROP PROCEDURE `OrderStatus`;
 CREATE DEFINER=`profetah`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `OrderStatus`(IN` 
 OrderID` INT, OUT `output1` TEXT) NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL 
 SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN
 SELECT OrderStatus INTO output1
 FROM `ProfetaOrders`
 WHERE TransactionID=OrderID;
 END
```

**Error**

DataError
ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select @output1 as `output1`' at line 1

Please help.
Regards.

Comment: Your query does not contain any part that would create an error message which complains about `select @output1 as output1`. So please either add the actual error message or the actual code.

Comment: @Solarflare It is actually the exact error I am getting. 
The only thing i did not mention thinking it is important is I am calling this procedure from API connection site integromat.com

Comment: Your code does not contain any reference to `@output1`, while your error message does. So you are missing something. Maybe it is part of the code that calls that procedure, so add that. Currently, we cannot tell you why you get that error because we don't see the code that is responsible for that error.

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks for reply. I dont't know how integromat is calling this proceadure. I have submitted request to them. Let's see what they reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in the code. It was actually from integromate.com
When contacted they solved this error from there side.

Regards.